# How can I configure dyndns service in dlink DIR-600L router to access my local server via internet?

Tags: router, webserver, dynamic-dns

The following link is the graphical representation of the networking done in my home.

I have a DLINK DIR-600L Wireless router which is connected to modem via a switch. As this router have DDNS service enabled, I registered a domain in 'dyndns.org' and configured the router.

Then I setup a webserver under my router network(3) and setup the port forwarding in router from ip '192.167.0.101'. Now I can access the hosted website anywhere in my home in ip address '192.168.0.2'. Then I configured the DDNS to ip '192.168.0.2'. The problem is that this dyndns domain name can only be used inside my home network(1). I need to access my site from anywhere in world via internet. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to forward the port in your modem as well, and point the DDNS to your external address.

Comment: I also had that idea. But the modem and router is connected using a switch. How can i port forward in a switch?

Comment: You can't. But you don't need to, since switches work at a lower level.

Comment: I already done port forwarding in router. IP Address: 192.167.0.101,
Public port: 80,
Private port : 8080,
Traffic type: TCP & UDP.

Comment: What if I connect another dlink router between modem and switch? Also I could set that router with the ddns service. Can this solve it?

Comment: The more routers you have, the more port forwarding you need to do.

Comment: Yes. But currently, i think the external ip address is reaching ip 192.168.0.1 of switch. I usually get modem configuration page in that ip. So, If I connect modem to internet port of router and connect that switch under that router, can it receive request from external ip?

Comment: +1 for the 'and point the DDNS to your external address'